# nodemailer not sending email from node server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nodemailer

I have created a form with a React front end and a node.js and nodemailer backend. I am trying to send that data in an email. I can send it to the back end. There it is received perfectly fine. However, I am getting an issue when sending out the email as the 'mail not sent' error is getting executed from the Transporter.sendMail function and I'm not sure why.

Would love to get some help. Please see the code below for my server. I have obviously removed my authentication details for security purposes.

console log error:

[0] not sent

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const path = require('path');
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 5000;
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
  })
);

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'email',
    pass: 'password',

  }
});




app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Hello from .get /home", req.body.generalDetails, req.body.firstName, req.body.mName );

})






app.post("/home", (req, res) => {

  var mailOptions = {
                from: 'email',
                to: 'email',
                subject: 'Hello',
                text: req.body.generalDetails,

            }

            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Mail not sent');
                } else {
                    console.log('Mail sent');
                }
            });

  let data = [{
    //page one data
    generalDetails: req.body.generalDetails,
    fName: req.body.fName,
    mName: req.body.mName,
    lName: req.body.lName,
    email: req.body.email,

   }];

   res.json(data);
 }

);



app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

In recent node mailer changes, they have introduced, auth key in auth.Currently you are passing password and user in auth object.I made those changes and node mailer start working. Pass

```
`auth: {
api_key: config.mailer.auth.pass
```

}`

I hope so it will work.